# Vue ignoring MathML tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

On my site a user can embed MathML content anywhere on the page using the CMS, which turns into:

```
<div id="app">
  ...
  <math style="font-family:Tahoma" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mroot><mn>12</mn><mn>3</mn></mroot></math>
  ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({ el: '#app' })
</script>
```

But this generates a TypeError: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined"

Is it possible to ignore tags starting with `<math>` (including its children)? I've tried using [ignoreElements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements) but still get the same error.

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'math'
];
```

Comment: You can use `v-pre` directive: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-dl6x7

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!